# INFO going to shutdown

Tags: ruby, google-analytics, sinatra, localhost

I tried to run the app, nothing happens on 4567, so I `CTRL+C` but keep getting this message and the computer just sits there

```
Juan-Gallardos-MacBook-Pro:lagunacave juangallardo$ ruby main.rb
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks-1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers-1.2.7
Ignoring kgio-2.9.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine kgio-2.9.2
Ignoring pg-0.17.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg-0.17.1
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.9 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3-1.3.9
[2015-03-12 18:56:47] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-03-12 18:56:47] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-12-25) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
== Sinatra/1.4.5 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2015-03-12 18:56:47] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1262 port=4567
^C== Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
[2015-03-12 18:57:12] INFO  going to shutdown ...
```

until I shutdown. This has been happening to apps that I add Google analytics to as shown in this tutorial

http://pydelion.com/2013/02/25/adding-google-analytics-to-sinatra-application/

which recommends the **rack-google-analytics** gem

This is my new file

#### main.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'slim'
require 'sass'
require 'sinatra/reloader' if development?
require 'rack-google-analytics'
use Rack::GoogleAnalytics, :tracker => 'UA-60714558-1'

get('/styles.css'){ scss :styles }

get '/' do
  slim :home
end

get '/contact' do
  slim :contact
end

get '/privacy' do
  slim :contact
end

not_found do
  slim :not_found
end
```

The previous file which was functional had

#### main.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'slim'
require 'sass'
require 'sinatra/reloader' if development?

get('/styles.css'){ scss :styles }

get '/' do
  slim :home
end

get '/contact' do
  slim :contact
end

get '/privacy' do
  slim :contact
end

not_found do
  slim :not_found
end
```

Comment: Did you get errors when you installed analytics with `gem install rack-google-analytics` ? Given your error message, it looks like some dependencies are missing.

Comment: @ericd no, it seemed to have installed a lot of its dependencies. But I may be interpreting things wrong. I ended up just linking the javascript file since this gem overcomplicated things and had poor documentation.